# Suffering from unstable and inconsistent Sandbox behaviors

Tags: paypal

I am suffering in the last few days from inconsistent behaviors of PayPal sendbox,

In the last two days I already encountered:

- Few minutes ago (12:30 UTC) my REST API apps were gone and I received a yellow 'we'r sorry' message.
- REST-API Authorization endpoint give me sometimes: 'statusCode: 400, Unable to generate token', and sometimes: statusCode: 503 Http/1.1 Service Unavailable and sometimes it works.

Whats going on? is there any 'system health' or paypal reports somewhere about instability modes?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Asaf, was this issue ever resolved? I have similar problem testing REST API - all i get is: The requested URL /cgi-bin/ppapi was not found on this server.

Comment: This is unbelievable for a large payment system like PayPal. PayPal Sandbox is a nightmare. It's too unstable. Many many error and misbehaviors. My app tested and was fine last week, without any error, I got many strange error the day before yesterday. It fixed yesterday without zero changes, it has some other issue for login today! It happened a couple of time before.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with PayPal.

It should be fine now.

Comment: Its not, I'm still getting errors, and things like "The requested URL /cgi-bin/ppapi was not found on this server"